# Create home site app is missing in my home site settings

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-teams, communication-site, microsoft-viva

As per the below MSDN PowerShell command, I have configured the home site for my tenant.

```
Set-SPOHomeSite -HomeSiteUrl "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/homesite"
```

The intention behind is this to configure this home site app in the "Microsoft Teams", here I was referring to this article [SharePoint Home Site App](https://www.impactory.de/en/sharepoint-home-site-app-2/#), as per this I am supposed to see the "**Create Home site app**" from this navigation - **Home site -> Site Settings -> Create Home site app** as shown in the below image. But I am missing the "**Teams**" section and **Create Home site app** in my home site, just I could see the "Office 365":

[image]

Anyone could please elaborate on this and are we missing any prior configuration on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Home site app is now known as the **Viva Connections**.

Brief steps to add Viva Connections for Microsoft Teams desktop:

1. [Set up a home site in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/03/17/set-up-a-home-site-in-sharepoint-online/)
2. [Enable and Customize Global navigation](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/04/04/enable-and-customize-global-navigation-in-the-sharepoint-app-bar/) in [SharePoint app bar](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/24/introducing-a-sharepoint-app-bar-that-features-global-navigation/).
3. Create a Viva Connections app package in PowerShell
4. Provide tenant and site information to create the package
5. Upload the Viva Connections desktop package in the Teams Admin Center
6. Manage and pin the app by default for your users

For detailed information, follow below documentation:

[Add Viva Connections for Microsoft Teams desktop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/viva-connections)